# Slow boot but no hints in dmesg

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, dmesg

I have had problems with really slow boots on my Ubuntu 16.04. I dual boot with windows and at the grub loader i choose Ubuntu and the screen turns purple. Then it stays purple for up to 5 minutes before the "drumming" and the login screen appears. I have checked dmesg but it says that the boot finishes in 8.5s...  The last line is: 
[    8.526194] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
This the full dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/YkQfB4Pm
I have checked if my swap is correct in the fstab and it is. I have tried alot of thing but cant figure out what the problem is... 
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also post /var/log/boot.log and /var/log/syslog? There might be clues there, especially since the kernel itself appears to be booting normally.

Comment: I have checked for any clues in those files but couldn't find anything useful. I have removed the quiet splash line so I can see the messages from the boot sequence and it seems the system is being stalled some how between the grub boot loader and the actual boot sequence. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Nope. One thing you could do it try to measure precisely how long the stall lasts. If this is a constant value (precisely five minutes, for example), then it could mean *something* is waiting and a timeout is reached. If this is random... I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel log doesn't show any kernel related delay issues, the problem is more likely to be in the userspace size of the boot.  One can see what consumes the most time in the boot using:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

or a more graphical way:

```
systemd-analyze  plot > plot.svg
eog plot.svg
```

Comment: Hello!
Iv'e tried the systemd-analyze blame also, but the longest time there is 667ms... This is the full log: http://pastebin.com/FZfh48rr

Comment: Hrm, I'm not sure how to proceed on that. I wonder if anyone else has some ideas. Sorry.

Comment: It seems as if there is something stalling the system between the grub boot loader and the actual boot sequence... You have any clue about what that might be?

Comment: Is there anything particular about your grub install? What kind of BIOS do you have (UEFI?). Can you post your /boot/grub/grub.cfg?